# Input, raw_input, Iteration

Tags: python-2.7

I am practicing to refresh my python abilities, since I took that class last year. Here is what I would like to do. I would like users to be prompted to enter integers in the PHONE field as long as there is any other TYPE entered in the field,and when only integers are entered the iteration should break.

```
d = 0
done = 2
while done != "quit": 

print ""
print ""


print "Please, fill in the following:"

print "Type your Name, then press enter." 
name= raw_input("NAME >> ")

print "Type your First Name, then press enter." 
fname= raw_input("FIRST NAME >>: ")

print "Type your Phone Number, then press enter." 

tel= input("+509-")


print "e-mail address"
mail= raw_input("Ex: someone@domain.com >>: ")

print "Your address."
address= raw_input(" Address>>: ")
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not completely clear. Are you saying you want to keep asking for the phone number until only integers were entered?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want it to do: keep asking for the phone until only integers are entered. 

Sorry for the confusion, and anticipated thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most optimal solution, and perhaps this was already obvious to you, but it's the only one I know off the top of my head. You can also add further criteria for what a valid phone number is such as number of digits.

```
tel = "meh"
validChars = '+-0123456789'
valid = False
while not valid:
    print("Type your Phone Number, then press enter.")
    tel= input("+509-")
    valid = True
    for char in tel:
        if not char in validChars:
            valid = False
            break
```

Comment: Thanks a lot CodeMonkey,

I only had to change tel= input... to tel= raw_input